# removing specific columns in R

Tags: r

I am using `findCorrelation` function in R:

```
highCorr <- findCorrelation(correlations, cutoff = .60,names = FALSE)
```

The function return columns numbers/names that are 0.6 an above correlated.

I want to remove these columns.

I don't know how to do this because first if i remove them one at a time the column number change but, I want to try few cutoff threshold and would like to do this automatically.

Comment: are you trying to remove the columns from a data frame/data table? If so, what's the name of the data frame/table

Comment: `highCorr[highCorr$numbers > cutoff]` will return only values greater than the cutoff you specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your original data are a correlation matrix you can do the following:

```
library(caret) #findCorrelation comes from this library
set.seed(1)

#create simulated data for correlation matrix
mydata <- matrix(data = rnorm(100,mean = 100, sd = 3), nrow = 10, ncol = 10)

#create correlation matrix
correlations <- cor(mydata)

#index correlations at cutoff
corr_ind <- findCorrelation(correlations, cutoff = .2)

#remove columns from original data based on index value
remove_corrs <- mydata[-c(corr_ind)]
```